# Perform context specific action with templated variable type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

This question was marked duplicate to a solution that uses `boost` for keeping dynamic polymorphism, even though i stated explicitly that I can't use `boost`.

I want to have multiple contexts that are instanciated somewhere else.
Now we want to set key-value variables to some value of type `T`, context-dependent.

A `variable` class is a handle to set an arbitrary type to some value.

Each context handles the variable setting differently (namely these are graphics backends.) For that, the `Context::magically_set` method could be specialized for each supported `T`.

But each context handles each supported `T` differently.

Here's my "working" code if virtual member functions could be templated:

```
class Context {
public:
    template<typename T>
    virtual void magically_set(const T &value);
};

class ContextA : public Context {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void magically_set(const std::string &name, const T &value) override;
    // somewhere else: T-specific implementation for this context.
};

class ContextB : public Context {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void magically_set(const std::string &name, const T &value) override;
    // somewhere else: T-specific implementation for this different context.
};

template<typename T>
class Variable {
public:
    Variable(std::string name, Context *context)
        : name{name}, context{context} {}

    void set(const T &value) {
        this->context->magically_set(this->name, value);
    }

    std::string name;
    Context *context;
};
```

and the usage:

```
ContextB ctx_b;
Variable<float> test{"index", &ctx_b};
Variable<vec3> vectest{"color", &ctx_b};
test.set(0.1337f);
vectest.set({0.0, 0.0, 1.0});
```

How can I make this work? I can use anything supported by c++14, but no `boost`.

Comment: Does context has a limited number of `T` supported ?

Comment: Yes, because each `T` needs special handling (we're talking about shader uniforms here.)

Comment: So you may have several `virtual void magically_set`, one by supported type.

Comment: Why was the question flagged duplicate? I stated that I can't use boost, and the "duplicate" uses boost as the only option for maintaining dynamic polymorphism...  @Jarod42, yes this is a good idea although it will severely clutter the base class. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have problems to supply the Context to the Variable you could do something like the following:

```
template<typename T, typename C>
class Variable {
public:
    Variable(std::string name, C &context)
        : name{name}, context{context} {}

    void set(const T &value) {
        this->context->magically_set(this->name, value);
    }

    std::string name;
    C &context;
};
```

you now have to declare the Variables as follows:

```
typedef ContextB ActiveContext;

ContextB ctx_b;
Variable<float, ActiveContext> test{"index", ctx_b};
Variable<vec3, ActiveContext> vectest{"color", ctx_b};
test.set(0.1337f);
vectest.set({0.0, 0.0, 1.0});
```

PS: you should make `Variable::name` and `Variable::context` private.

Comment: Sorry, but this would lead to a compiletime context dependency, but the context selection must happen dynamically.